# write javascript inside php code

Tags: javascript, php

Any idea how I can write this code in side a php script:

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('lightpos<?=$the_job_id;?>').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fadepos<?=$the_job_id;?>').style.display='block'"><img src='img/remove.png' onmouseover=this.src='img/remove_light.png' onmouseout=this.src='img/remove.png'></a>
```

I have tried, this but not working:

```
<?php
  echo" <a href = 'javascript:void(0)' onclick = 'document.getElementById('lightpos<?=$the_job_id;?>').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fadepos<?=$the_job_id;?>').style.display='block' '><img src='img/remove.png' onmouseover=this.src='img/remove_light.png' onmouseout=this.src='img/remove.png'></a> ";
?>
```

any idea?

Comment: The first one will just work fine in a PHP script. If the second one doesn't work, it's mostest likely due to quotation mark problems. You might have to escape them. The more nested strings you have, the nastier it gets, and that's why you should avoid something like this all together.

Comment: yes I know...this is that I dont know how to fix it

Comment: If you look at the color coding above it will give you some hints ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is DON'T ECHO SO MUCH OF HTML, the reason why your code was failing because you were using `<?=` inside an `echo` statement which is nothing but a shorthand of `echo`

So do it like this,

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "clicked(<?=$the_job_id;?>, <?=$the_job_id;?>)">
    <img src='img/remove.png' onmouseover="this.src='img/remove_light.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/remove.png'" />
</a>

<script>
    //If you are sure that lightposid and fadeposid are going to be same
    //than 1 parameter is sufficient
    function clicked(lightposid, fadeposid) {
        document.getElementById('lightpos' + lightposid).style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fadepos' + fadeposid).style.display='block';
    }
</script>
```

And for god sake, use `:hover` pseudo instead of using `mouseover` and `mouseout` events...

And if you are looking to swap the URLs of the `img` tag than use a function instead.

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CuLCt/)</kbd> (Console Log will return undefined because I don't have the elements having `id` of *lightpos1* and *fadepos1*)

Note: In the above demo, am using `1, 1` as the values of `<?=$the_job_id;?>`. So they will be your real job ids..

---

If you are willing to remove the `img` tag, replace it with a `span` element like

```
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "clicked(<?=$the_job_id;?>, <?=$the_job_id;?>)">
    <span class="remove"></span>
</a>
```

Now, use something like this in your CSS

```
.remove {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px; /* Set height and width according to your requirements */
    background-image: url('URL_OF_THE_REMOEV_IMAGE_GOES_HERE');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: 1px solid red; /* Remove this after you set the height and width correctly */
    vertical-align: middle; /* Not sure but I think you will need this */
}

.remove:hover {
    background-image: url('REMOVE_LIGHT_PNG_URL_GOES_HERE');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all dont use single quotes('), use double quotes(") or no quotesfor variables.

Your code has varaiable **$the_job_id** under single quotes.

Try this code:

```
<?php
echo '<a href ="javascript:void(0)" onclick ="clickFunc()"><img src="img/remove.png" onmouseover="Over()" onmouseout="Out()"></a>'
?>
```

And use this script:

```
    <script>
function clickFunc() {
    document.getElementById("lightpos'.$the_job_id.'").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("fadepos'.$the_job_id.'").style.display = "block"
}

function Over() {
    this.src = "img/remove_light.png";
}

function Out() {
    this.src = "img/remove.png";
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Your `clickFunc()` is incorrect, are you going to iterate that function for each anchor tag?